# Snowsql File Formatting

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I code via command line, the file format options to leave the backslash character as data to load and not trigger a field break? I've got lots of backslashes in the data file that needs to be loaded.  I have Pipes '|' as my field breaks.

I've tried using ESCAPE, FIELD_DELIMITER, etc.  Many variations.

Recognizing potential redundancy, I'll gather the full details of the named format content, but overall, was just desiring to understand which combinations of Format commands ignores backslash as a delimiter function, and focuses solely on my stated field delimiter of a Pipe.  Thank you.

Update - checked my Piped_CSV_STG record, and there ended up being a clash of commands by those who created that record.  Thanks for raising the question.

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the actual command you are running, some sample data and any other relevant information (e.g. if you are using a pre-defined file format, include it’s definition). Use editable text rather than images

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Running from SSIS off snowsql.exe:    -c stage -q "COPY INTO OCUDS_STG.STG_OAH_PROV FROM @OCUDR_Stage9/DL30063PRV_I_MONTHLY_20230303000000.txt.gz file_format = (format_name = 'PIPED_CSV_STG' FIELD_DELIMITER='|' ESCAPE="\\" TRIM_SPACE=TRUE error_on_column_count_mismatch=FALSE ) "   I've also tried several other of the options as well.    Here's one of the data records with backslashes causing issues (I need to load the backslashes and commas):   432132152|VRG00010116522|433326666|MXXXXX, N.P., JCCCCC\|JCCCCC\||MXXXXX|||U|50|Nurse Practitioner|||||

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi - as I said in my comment, please update your question with the additional information - don’t add it it comments. If information is spread across the original question and, potentially, multiple comments, it makes it very difficult to follow

Comment: Also, why are you using a named file format and then also format parameters (which should be defined in the file format)? One or other is redundant. Please update your question with the definition of the named file format PIPED_CSV_STG

Comment: Easy sir.  First time posting to this site and didn't completely absorb all requirements in doing so.  I'll pivot further to the question.